# How do we want to test Hyperthreading performance boosts for the SuperUser Blog?

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

For the [Super User Questions of the Week #15](https://meta.superuser.com/q/2542/19943) the highest voted answer was [How much speedup does a hyper thread give? (in theory).](https://superuser.com/questions/279629/how-much-speedup-does-a-hyper-thread-give-in-theory)

While we should be looking at what theoretical boost Hyperthreading **can** give I believe we also need to bolster that and physically quantify the "real-world" boost that Hyperthreading gives.  To that end I would like to gather opinions and programs that are suitable for proving whether this feature is useful or not.

At the moment I can see the following tests being valid

> - Prime95
> - 7-Zip using a large file collection & 8 threads
> - Handbrake H.264 encoder (does anyone know if there is an accepted "standard" video to convert? Probably not necessary so long as the tests are consistent...)

As I see it we can also gather some information from http://www.cpubenchmark.net and compare CPUs with and without Hyperthreading to get some vague correlation.

If anyone has any good multithreaded programs, appropriate single-threaded applications or even just best-practice test procedures I'd be grateful if you could let me know.

Answer (score 6):

If you have any video games (I know you've got Portal 2), you could compare the performance when hyperthreaded vs. when not. Portal 2 has an option under the advanced video settings to enable or disable multi-core processing, too. You could benchmark it by looking at the average FPS.

Comment: That is actually a very good point, a lot of games these days use a high level of multithreading to support different task such as the renderer, physics, audio, and other jobs.

Answer (score 3):

The best links I ever found on HT performance were at

http://ixbtlabs.com/articles3/cpu/archspeed-2009-3-p1.html

and

http://ixbtlabs.com/articles3/cpu/archspeed-2009-4-p2.html

However, from what I understand, HT is much better on the newer Sandy Bridge & beyond than it was on the original i7 -- so you might check for updated articles on that site.